# First and last elements in list using RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, zend-framework, recursion, iterator, spl

I'm using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to loop over `Zend_Navigation`, which is basically a list of nested `<ul>` and `<li>` tags:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $container, 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
foreach ($iterator as $page) {
    ...
    // isLast()?
    // isFirst()?
}
```

How to determine, whether the currently iterated element (`$page`) is first or last element on current level?
I need to add `first` and `last` class attribute to those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [getDepth()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php) to query the depth of the tag. When the depth increases, you're at a new level and should add a `first` attribute. When the depth decreases between tags, that tells you the previous tag was the last in its level and you should add a `last` attribute to it. This means you will have to read the next tag before you can finish processing the current tag.